# Calling a sql query in an excel table - declared variables

Tags: sql-server, excel

I am trying to run the following stored procedure as a query in an excel table:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare @RefList as RefList

--insert into table parameter list of references
insert into @RefList (ColA)
select distinct ColA
from Pricing_Metrics
where Range_Name = 'Model_Name' and Field_Value = 'ModelA'

--run stored procedure passing list of references as parameter
execute [View_Agg_Data] @RefList
```

However it fails to run with the error tsaying the query did not run, or the database table could not be opened. However all other standard queries work.

I think the part here:

```
--insert into table parameter list of references
insert into @RefList (ColA)
select distinct ColA
from Pricing_Metrics
where Range_Name = 'Model_Name' and Field_Value = 'ModelA'
```

is failing, however I cannot change the stored procedure which has a parameter of a list.

The query works fully on sql itself.

Comment: Could you post the actual message? Also are their parameters to this procedure? It looks like RefList is a user defined table type?

Comment: That's really the full extent of the message. Yes RefList is a user defined table type. Just a column with around 2000 rows.

Comment: So do you pass in this parameter? In the code you posted here there is no parameter. And the ACTUAL message is extremely helpful. A paraphrased message is not. And since you are calling this from Excel maybe the VBA.

Comment: I am not using VBA for this, I am using a data connection with an excel table. The message is exactly as typed. Yes it is ran a parameter, the RefList is the parameter which is passed when I execute the stored procedure.

Comment: I suspect you can't use table valued parameters like this from Excel. But from the code posted I don't see why you need to pass one in, There is no reference to anything outside the code posted.

Comment: @SeanLange The reference is here: execute [View_Agg_Data] @ RefList

Comment: But that isn't a parameter, it is a local variable in the code you posted. You declare it right there after setting nocount on.

Comment: @SeanLange The stored procedure takes in that local variable. It's not a parameter in the general sense, but that the stored procedure does is sets up a dyanmic query and runs sp_exectuesql for that dynamic query, but it requires a list of reference, which is that the local variable @ refList does

Comment: So is it a parameter or not? There is no gray area here. I could probably have helped you already if you would just provide the details. Does this procedure have any parameters? How are you calling this from Excel? I can't see your screen and have no idea of any details other than what you have posted which at this point is vague at best.

Comment: @SeanLange I'm not sure what else I can say - it is a parameter, without the @ RiskRef being put right after the stored procedure, nothing would happen. I am calling it from excel by setting up a data connection with sql server and putting in the exact query in my post. The idea is that the stored procedure takes a table, selects from this table, does something and returns a result.

Comment: OK. Well since you refuse to share enough code for me to help all I can say I truly hope you can figure this out. The code you posted does NOT receive a parameter period. It is a local variable which passes to another procedure. I have been trying to get you to share the procedure code but you don't want to for whatever reason. Good luck!!!

Comment: @SeanLange You didn't ask for the procedure code once... I can post it if required.

Comment: The procedure you are calling is the only on that should matter here. The View_Agg_Data is irrelevant to the issue at hand. Your post says the procedure posted which I guess I did not explicitly suggest you should post but gosh it couldn't have been a far stretch to think that others would need to see that detail. We are 20 comments into this already still trying to get the basic details for others to have enough information to help. Have you searched that particular error message? It seems it has been posted about a lot of times.